# Proof by Exhaustive Computation for small initial segment of natural numbers (in Coq)

Tags: natural-numbers, reflection

I have two functions `f, g : nat -> nat`. Let's pretend that `f` and `g` are cheap to compute.

I would like to prove something like

```
Lemma upto_20 (n : nat):
  n <= 20 -> f n = g n.
```

For the proof, I could write `destruct n` 20 times, but that seems suboptimal. Is there some way with which I can finish the proof like this?

```
Proof.
compute n from 0 to 20.
Qed.
```

Comment: Does `repeat` work?

Answer (score 5):

You can prove in userland that these kind of problems are decidable (I am not too familiar with the stdlib so it can probably be golfed down):

```ml
Require Nat.

Definition Decidable (t : Prop) : Prop := t \/ (t -> False).

Lemma dec_bounded
  (P : nat -> Prop) (Pdec : forall k, Decidable (P k))
  (bound : nat) : Decidable (forall (k : nat), k <= bound -> P k).
Proof.
induction bound as [|n  IHn].
  - destruct (Pdec O) as [PO | nPO].
    + left; intros k klt; inversion klt; assumption.
    + right; intro nPk; apply nPO; auto.
  - destruct (Pdec (S n)) as [PSn | nPSn].
    + destruct IHn as [Pk | nPk].
      * left; intros k klt; inversion klt; auto.
      * right; intro nPSk; apply nPk; auto.
    + right; auto.
Defined.
```

For your special case, I also need to prove that equality of natural numbers is decidable. I am using `Defined` everywhere so that Coq will happily compute with all of these things.

```
Definition dec_nat (k : nat) : forall (n : nat), Decidable (k = n).
Proof.
induction k as [|k IHk]; intro n; destruct n.
  - left; reflexivity.
  - right; inversion 1.
  - right; inversion 1.
  - destruct (IHk n) as [Pk | nPk].
    + left; auto.
    + right; intro contra; apply nPk; inversion contra; auto.
Defined.
```

And then you can add a little glue to grab the goal, run the decision procedure and apply the resulting proof:

```ml
Ltac bounded_equality := match goal with
  |- ?n <= ?bnd -> ?f ?n = ?g ?n =>
    let k := fresh "k" in
    let val := ltac:(eval compute in (dec_bounded (fun k => f k = g k) (fun k => dec_nat (f k) (g k)) bnd)) in
    match val with
      | (or_introl ?prf) => eapply prf
      | ?p => idtac "Couldn't find a proof"
    end
  end.
```

In action it looks something like this:

```ml
Definition double (n : nat) := n + n.

Lemma upto_20 (n : nat) :
  n <= 20 -> double n = 2 * n.
  bounded_equality.
Qed.
```

Comment: This is great. Indeed I would like to know if there are any more succinct techniques using stdlib or ssreflect tactics that does not require rolling your own